# How do I handle stopping my service?

Tags: bash, init.d

I've turned a program I wrote into a service, and I have a bash script that runs to start up the actual program, since there are things that have to be started in a particular order. The contents of the startup script (called with `start-stop-daemon` from the init.d script look like :

```
./rfid_reader &
sleep 2
java ReaderClass &
```

This works fine, but how do I go about killing them when it comes time to stop the process?
I've seen pidfiles used, do I just get the PIDs of the two programs, write them to a file, and then kill them when it comes time to shut them down, or do I have to `ps -ef | grep program` to get their PIDs?

Comment: How about `pid1=$(pidof program_name) && pid2=$(pidof other_name) && kill $pid1 $pid2`? or just `kill $(pidof program_name) $(pidof other_name)`

Comment: These work, I figured there was a standard way of doing it, I guess this is the standard way

Comment: The standard was is to call the same `/etc/rc.d/initfile stop` you used to `/etc/rc.d/initfile start` the daemon (or `systemctl stop prog_name` to invoke the stop service in the `systemd` world)

Comment: Okay, and within that stop function I use `kill program_name`

Comment: If you are in the `initfile` world, just copy an existing initfile from `/etc/rc.d` and modify/rename it to fit your service so that it provides a pid file in your *state directory* that will be killed by calling `/etc/rc.d/your_prog stop` when you are ready to stop the daemon. You can do the same thing with systemd service files, although there are a few more rules to worry about in crafting a systemd service file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `killall` is a good idea to do this. You'd better to record the `PID` of the program started in background in some file(e.g. `PID_FILE`) and then `kill $(<$PID_FILE)` to stop it.

Please refer to [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30370/how-to-get-the-pid-of-the-last-executed-command-in-shell-script) for how to get the `PID` the previous started background program.

Comment: @BrydonGibson Glad to help :-)

Comment: Except the `UUOC` (unnecessary use of `cat`) could be replaced with `kill $(<$PID_FILE)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for your suggestion, updated the answer.

Comment: Sure, it's a good learning opportunity. Any time you find yourself wanting to do `cat whatever`, if you are not actually *concatenating* files, there is probably a more proper way of doing it `:)`

Comment: I also googled http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html and recognised I've been using a lot of UUOx in my daily work. Really good blog to read and thank you again :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the name of your program, you can kill them as below :

```
killall -KILL program_name
```

Comment: `-KILL`? Really? Is this normal practice in your part of the woods?

Comment: May want to be expressly clear that `program` is `program_name` just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes, program_name also works, as Brydon originally stated
ps -ef | grep program
I thought to repeat it for consistency sake

Comment: Not the best solution but it doesn't require to get the PID of the program

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : should I avoid using the -KILL option ?

Comment: If you want to give the process a fighting chance at shutting down properly, absolutely.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I tend to use it because, again, I can kill by providing the program name instead of the PID.